# Flink Application on EKS is not fetching events pushed to kinesis when flink is down

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, amazon-kinesis, flink-checkpoint

I have a flink application which is running on EKS in application mode.
I am doing helm install to start the application
`helm --install flinks -n default ./ -f values.yaml`
pushed events and flink is writing to s3.
I uninstalled with helm
`helm un flinks -n default`
pushed events to kinesis and then reinstalled using helm then flink is not able to read events that were pushed when it is down.
`setProperty(ConsumerConfigConstants.STREAM_INITIAL_POSITION, "LATEST"))`

I have tried with savepoint using REST API
`curl --location 'http://localhost:8081/jobs/1a0b128962fc88e99cabe77a29dfbf7d/savepoints' \ --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \ --data '{"target-directory": "s3://<path_to_savepoint>"}'`

then
`helm upgrade --install flinks -n defalut ./ -f values.yaml --set savepoints.restorePath=s3://<path_to_savepoint>`

tried even with ExternalizedCheckpointCleanup
`checkpointConfig.setExternalizedCheckpointCleanup(ExternalizedCheckpointCleanup.RETAIN_ON_CANCELLATION)`